# Backbone Event Map Doesn't Recognize Classes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

Stack.

I'm using Backbone's event map in my View.

JS:

```
events: {
    "click .edit-info-button": "pullEdits"
},
pullEdits: function(e){
    // Get the value of the button clicked
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".edit-info-button").click(function(){parseEdits(this.value);});
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="button edit-info-button" value="edit address">EDIT</button>
```

When edit-info-button is a class, the event listener does not work. pullEdits() never fires.

When I change edit-info-button into an id ("click #edit-info-button", "button id='edit-info-button', etc.) pullEdit() and all functions after it run successfully.

The issue is, the page I'm working on needs multiple edit buttons and I'd like to give them the same class and pull the value instead of giving them all unique ids.

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: What is the element of your view's `el`?

Comment: What is your view based on?

Comment: el: function(){
  return $("#main-container");
 },


#main-container is a div that holds the entire content of the page.

Comment: Seems to work fine http://jsbin.com/defoneri/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
...
events: {
    "click .edit-info-button": "pullEdits"
},
pullEdits: function(e){
    var val = $(e.target).attr('value')
    return parseEdits( val );
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it (as well as another issue I was having)!